# R data.table - group by column includes list

Tags: r, data.table

I try to use the group by function of the data.table package in R.

```
start <- as.Date('2014-1-1')
end <- as.Date('2014-1-6')
time.span <- seq(start, end, "days")
a <- data.table(date = time.span, value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), group=c('a','a','b','b','a','b'))

        date  value group
1   2014-01-01  1   a
2   2014-01-02  2   a
3   2014-01-03  3   b
4   2014-01-04  4   b
5   2014-01-05  5   a
6   2014-01-06  6   b

a[,mean(value),by=group]
> group      V1
 1:   a    2.6667
 2:   b    4.3333
```

This works fine.

Since i am working with Dates it can happen that a special date not only has one but two groups.

```
a <- data.table(date = time.span, value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), group=list('a',c('a','b'),'b','b','a','b'))

        date   value  group
1   2014-01-01  1   a
2   2014-01-02  2   c("a", "b")
3   2014-01-03  3   b
4   2014-01-04  4   b
5   2014-01-05  5   a
6   2014-01-06  6   b

a[,mean(value),by=group]
> Error in `[.data.table`(a, , mean(value), by = group) : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,2,1,1,1,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (6).
```

I would like that the group date with both groups will be used for calculating the mean of group a as well as of group b.

Expected results:

```
mean a: 2.6667
mean b: 3.75
```

Is that possible with the data.table package?

**Update**

Thx to akrun my initial issue is solved. After "splitting" the data.table and in my case calculate different factors (based on the groups) i need the data.table back in its "original" form with unique rows based on the date. My solution so far:

```
a <- data.table(date = time.span, value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), group=list('a',c('a','b'),'b','b','a','b'))
b <- a[rep(1:nrow(a), lengths(group))][, group:=unlist(a$group)]

       date   value  group
1   2014-01-01  1   a
2   2014-01-02  2   a
3   2014-01-02  2   b
4   2014-01-03  3   b
5   2014-01-04  4   b
6   2014-01-05  5   a
7   2014-01-06  6   b

# creates new column with mean based on group
b[,factor := mean(value), by=group] 

#creates new data.table c without duplicate rows (based on date) + if a row has group a & b it creates the product of their factors
c <- b[,.(value = unique(value), group = list(group), factor = prod(factor)),by=date]

date     value  group       factor
01/01/14    1   a           2.666666667
02/01/14    2   c("a", "b") 10
03/01/14    3   b           3.75
04/01/14    4   b           3.75
05/01/14    5   a           2.666666667
06/01/14    6   b           3.75
```

I guess it is not the perfect way to do it, but it works. Any suggestions how i could do it better?

Alternative solution (really slow!!!):

```
d <- a[rep(1:nrow(a), lengths(group))][,group:=unlist(a$group)][, mean(value), by = group]
for(i in 1:NROW(a)){
   y1 <- 1
   for(j in a[i,group][[1]]){
       y1 <- y1 * d[group==j, V1]
   }
   a[i, factor := y1]
}
```

**My fastest solution so far:**

```
# split rows that more than one group
b <- a[rep(1:nrow(a), lengths(group))][, group:=unlist(a$group)]
# calculate mean of different groups
b <- b[,factor := mean(value), by=group]
# only keep date + factor columns
b <- b[,.(date, factor)]
# summarise rows by date 
b <- b[,lapply(.SD,prod), by=date]
# add summarised factor column to initial data.table
c <- merge(a,b,by='date')
```

Any chance to make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to group by the row sequence, we `unlist` the `list` column ('group'), `paste` the `list` elements together (`toString(..)`), use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` with `direction='long'` to reshape it into 'long' format, and then get the `mean` of the 'value' column using 'grp' as the grouping variable.

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
a[, grp:= toString(unlist(group)), 1:nrow(a)]
cSplit(a, 'grp', ', ', 'long')[, mean(value), grp]
#  grp       V1
#1:   a 2.666667
#2:   b 3.750000
```

Just realized that another option using `splitstackshape` would be `listCol_l` which `unlist`s a `list` column into long form.  As the output is a `data.table`, we can use the `data.table` methods to calculate the `mean`.  It is much more compact to get the `mean`.

```
 listCol_l(a, 'group')[, mean(value), group_ul]
 #  group_ul       V1
 #1:        a 2.666667
 #2:        b 3.750000
```

---

Or another option without using `splitstackshape` would be to replicate the rows of the dataset by the `length` of the `list` element.  The `lengths` is a convenient wrapper for `sapply(group, length)` and is much faster.  Then, we change the 'group' column by `unlist`ing the original 'group' from 'a' dataset and get the `mean` of 'value', grouped by 'group'.

```
 a[rep(1:nrow(a), lengths(group))][,
        group:=unlist(a$group)][, mean(value), by = group]
 #  group       V1
 #1:     a 2.666667
 #2:     b 3.750000
```

Comment: GREAT! as far as i understand the "cSplit" splits rows that have two groups into two identical rows (one for the first group, one for the second) and afterwards we can easily use the normal data.table functions to calculate the mean( ). Really great solution @akrun - i had no clue about this "splitstackshape" package...

Comment: @RandomDude Yes, it splits the row with multiple elements into separate rows.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: where can i find the "lengths" function? Couldn't figure it out via google and according to my R Studio Version it is not available...

Comment: @RandomDude It is a `base R` function.  I think it was introduced in R 3.1.2 or so.  If you have an earlier version, it can be replaced with `sapply(group, length)`

Answer (score 0):

As shorter solution posted by @mike-h in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685396) also uses `unlist()` but groups by the remaining columns:

```r
require(data.table)

a = data.table(date = time.span,
               value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
               group = list('a',c('a','b'),'b','b','a','b'))

a[ , .(group = unlist(group)), .(date, value)][ , mean(value), group ]
```