# r extracting list elements from within dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am working with data where text comments are used to record a change in field contents rather than have an extra record and start/end dates. So the data looks like this:

```
Study  Fob
1      100
2      101 now 102
3      103
```

Note: test data can be constructed with:

```
df <- data.frame(Study = 1:3,
                 Fob = c("100", "101 now 102", "103"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to end up with the following form so I can process it essentially as a many-to-one conversion from Fob signal data to Study IDs:

```
Study  Fob
1      100
2      101
2      102
3      103
```

I can get rid of the superfluous text with:

```
df$IDs <- strsplit(df$Fob, "[^0-9]+")
```

which gets me to:

```
    Study  Fob          IDs
    1      100          100
    2      101 now 102  c("101", "102")
    3      103          103
```

but can't get any further. My first thought was to try and `replicate` the lines with multiple IDs (like 2) using a counter based on the length of the IDs, but adding `df$counter <- length(df$IDs)` just gets me a column with the value 3 because it is taking the length of the IDs column, not the element within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`.  We specify the pattern to `split`, use `fixed=FALSE` as the default is `fixed=TRUE` and the `direction = 'long'`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 'Fob', '[^0-9]+', fixed=FALSE, 'long')
#   Study Fob
#1:     1 100
#2:     2 101
#3:     2 102
#4:     3 103
```

`[^0-9]+` implies one more characters that are not a number.  So, it will split by all non-numeric characters leaving only the numeric part.  By default, `type.convert=TRUE`, so we will be getting numeric column `class` after the `split`.

Or instead of using `[^0-9]+`, a compact version would be `\\D+` to match all non-numeric characters (from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
cSplit(df, 'Fob', '\\D+', fixed=FALSE, 'long')
```

Comment: perfect thanks. will accept once the minimum time is up

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, it works.  I always forget about the `\\D+`

Comment: @JenB: FYI, there are already quite a number of questions on `cSplit` on SO, if you care for some more examples (e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155506/r-data-table-group-by-column-includes-list/32156057#32156057)).

Comment: Thanks - i will have a look. I hadn't seen splitstackshape before but it looks to be an excellent package to know about since I have starting processing real data (with all its inherent problems)