# Group a data.table using a column which is list

Tags: r, data.table

I have a really big problem and looping through the data.table to do what I want is too slow, so I am trying to get around looping. Let assume I have a data.table as follows:

```
a <- data.table(i = c(1,2,3), j = c(2,2,6), k = list(c("a","b"),c("a","c"),c("b")))

> a
  i j   k
1: 1 2 a,b
2: 2 2 a,c
3: 3 6   b
```

And I want to group based on the values in k. So something like this:

```
a[, sum(j), by = k]
```

right now I am getting the following error:

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(a, , sum(i), by = k) : 
 The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (2,2,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (3).
```

The answer I am looking for is to group first all the rows having "a" in column k and calculate sum(j) and then all rows having "b" and so on. So the desired answer would be:

```
k V1 
a 4
b 8
c 2
```

Any hint how to do it efficiently? I cant melt the column K by repeating the rows since the size of the data.table would be too big for my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R data.table - group by column includes list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155506/r-data-table-group-by-column-includes-list). I think this question is a duplicate, however it also provides better and more answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
a[, .(k = unlist(k)), by=.(i,j)][,sum(j),by=k]

   k V1
1: a  4
2: b  8
3: c  2
```

Answer (score 5):

If we are using `tidyr`, a compact option would be

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(a, k)[, sum(j) ,k]
#   k V1
#1: a  4
#2: b  8
#3: c  2
```

---

Or using the `dplyr/tidyr` pipes

```
unnest(a, k) %>%
       group_by(k) %>%
       summarise(V1 = sum(j))
#     k    V1
#   <chr> <dbl>
#1     a     4
#2     b     8
#3     c     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since by-group operations can be slow, I'd consider...

```
dat = a[rep(1:.N, lengths(k)), c(.SD, .(k = unlist(a$k))), .SDcols=setdiff(names(a), "k")]

   i j k
1: 1 2 a
2: 1 2 b
3: 2 2 a
4: 2 2 c
5: 3 6 b
```

We're repeating rows of cols `i:j` to match the unlisted `k`. The data should be kept in this format instead of using a list column, probably. From there, as in @MikeyMike's answer, we can `dat[, sum(j), by=k]`.

In data.table 1.9.7+, we can similarly do

```
dat = a[, c(.SD[rep(.I, lengths(k))], .(k = unlist(k))), .SDcols=i:j]
```

Comment: Answering separately since I was not optimistic that the other answerer would've noticed a comment and edited.

Comment: I am not following what you are doing here, and it is throwing an error when I try to run, do you know why is that? Error in lengths(k) : object 'k' not found

Comment: @newbie Yeah, I think I'm not seeing that error only because I'm on the devel version of the package (where we can refer to columns outside of .SD inside j). I'll edit to note this incompatibility and show another way. What I'm doing here is the same thing you see after unnest in akrun's answer or unlist in MikeyMike's, but might be more efficient since by-row operations (as in Mike's answer) can be slow.